# Select and change a single table cell color per row with angular 6

Tags: css, angular, select, background

I am trying to make a table in which I will be able to select a cell and change its color. Only 1 cell per row can be selected. When selected, its color should be red. When another is clicked, its color should change back to what it was before. I have been trying this for days, but no success. Only made it to change color of a whole row or column, but not a single cell. Can it be done?
Here is my template code:

```
 <table id="table2"  class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <th>Criteria</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let criter of rows;">          
      <td>{{ criter.criteria1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ criter.criteria2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ criter.criteria3 }}</td>
      <td>{{ criter.criteria4 }}</td>
    </tr>    
  <tbody>
  </table>
```

As for CSS, it just needs this class (I think):

```
.on { background-color: "red"; }
```

That is what got ATM. If you need some more info let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 changeBG(val) { // on tr element
    // val is event.target
    let table = document.querySelector('#table2');
    let selectedCells = table.getElementsByClassName('on');
    if (val.tagName !== 'TD') {
        return;
      }
    if (selectedCells.length) {
      selectedCells[0].className = '';
    }
    val.className = 'on';
  }
```

I don't know much about the angular dom interaction, but hopefully you can find the way through this

Comment: So, in tr tag I should put `(click)="changeBG(event.target)"`? And then just copy your code into mine? Sry, I am a bit dumb. x)

Comment: changeBG($event.target) and the function as usual but there is a warning with the code as angular is not meant for direct dom manipulation. But if you are making this for the web purpose then i think this would be okay and the code runs normally.

Comment: Ok, I think I made. Not exactly as you, tho. But thx anyway. :)